# GHOST - Post Feature Images not displaying in index.hbs

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, ghost-blog, express-handlebars

I wanted to create a custom landing page, so I made a home.hbs in addition to the index.hbs. I want to access home.hbs at `localhost:2368/` and index.hbs at `localhost:2368/blog/`

I got it to work, however, the feature images do not appear at `localhost:2368/blog/` or on the post page. They do, however at `localhost:2368/`. How can I fix this?

localhost:2368/blog/:
[image]

http://localhost:2368/blog/this-is-a-magic-post/
[image]

http://localhost:2368/
[image]
The landing page works exactly as expected.

This is my current routes.yaml file:

```
    routes:

collections:
  /blog/:
    permalink: /blog/{slug}/
    template: index

  /:
    permalink: /{slug}/
    template: home

taxonomies:
  tag: /tag/{slug}/
  author: /author/{slug}/
```

It's just the images. as you can see all the other data, such as reading time, date, and excerpt are present. Any help getting the images to be displayed in the post lists (index.hbs) and the posts would be appreciated.

I should also note that if you right click on the grey rectangles and click copy image address, it does give you the correct links which can then be put in the browser to view the image. So the image is there, it's just not displaying.

Thanks so much,
Camden

Answer (score 0):

Problem: Conflicting CSS with the header on these pages